# update Jira Issue with robot test results run through Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jira, robotframework

I am writing tests in RobotFramework and running them through Jenkins pipeline.
I would like to integrate the test results with associated Jira issue automatically? 
Can anybody explain step by step process on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Running tests in the pipeline. You mean on application build ? You'd want to be sure your tests are rock solid or your Jira ticket is gonna have a load of failure results attached to it. Depending on the processes you have in place with QA this may prove troublesome.

As for doing something like this automatically. We've done something similar in the past but we never wanted it to be part of the CI pipeline. It was a separate step that took the output.xml and uploaded them to Jira/X-Ray using Jira API. But it was a bespoke piece of software.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for the response. Is there a possibility to conditionally upload the test results into Jira?
And I am using Jira API too. This is the pipeline code I am using to update Jira issue: 
stage('JIRA') {
    steps {
        script {
          def comment = [ body: 'test comment from Jenkins' ]
          jiraAddComment idOrKey: '15765', input: comment
        }
    }
  }
But I am having issues like : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'jiraAddComment' found among steps